# error while making a list of a class and a class pointer

Tags: c++

i am trying to create a list like below. but there is error.

```
#ifndef CLASS1_H
#define CLASS1_H
#include <list>
class class2
{

};
class class3
{

};
class class1
{
public:
    typedef std::list<class2, class3*> m_list;
    m_list mylist;
};
#endif
```

the errors are:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/list:63:0,
                 from class1.h:3:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h: In instantiation of ‘std::_List_base<class2, class3*>’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:418:5:   instantiated from ‘std::list<class2, class3*>’
class1.h:16:9:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:294:9: error: ‘class3*’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:296:60: error: ‘class3*’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h: In instantiation of ‘std::list<class2, class3*>’:
class1.h:16:9:   instantiated from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:420:58: error: ‘class3*’ is not a class, struct, or union type
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:449:20: error: no members matching ‘std::list<class2, class3*>::_Base::_M_get_Tp_allocator’ in ‘class std::list<class2, class3*>::_Base’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.5.3/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:450:20: error: no members matching ‘std::list<class2, class3*>::_Base::_M_get_Node_allocator’ in ‘class std::list<class2, class3*>::_Base’
```

please anybody knows regarding this, kindly help me.

Comment: did you read list documentation?

Comment: yes, Chethan, i read it now... thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class list;
```

ignoring the allocator, `std::list` only take one type, not two.

allocator must be a class that satisfy the STL allocator requirement, it cannot be a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you want a map, not a list. If you do want a list with these two classes, you can use std::pair to make the two classes appear as a single element:

```
 typedef std::list<std::pair<class2, class3*> > m_list;
```